# Mysql: Add signed, negative value to unsigned with negative result

Tags: mysql

when subtracting two unsigned values in mysql, the result will also be unsigned. Since 5.5.5, mysql throws an error, if the result is negative.

In my case however, I need the negative result. I already learned, that this can be achieved by setting sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'.

Take the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `s`  INT SIGNED,
    `u1` INT UNSIGNED,
    `u2` INT UNSIGNED
);

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (-1, 0, 1);

SET sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
SELECT `u1` - `u2` FROM `test`;
```

The result of the SELECT is then -1, just as intended. But if I do,

```
SELECT `s` + `u1` FROM `test`;
```

which is mathematically the same, I still get the error "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range" (tested with mysql 5.5.29).

I know, this can by fixed by casting the unsigned value, but I would like to know, whether there is a global solution like for the subtraction, where I do not have to change all affected queries.

After all I wonder, why this addition of a negative value is not covered by NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION. Is this intended or maybe a bug?

Comment: In Server version:5.6.14-log MySQL Community Server (GPL) we have the same error. We can suppress error by doing: SELECT `s` + (`u1` - 0) FROM `test`;

Comment: Works for me too. This solution, however, would also require to modify all the queries in the code, just like casting.